# Rails 4 scope models : only Parents who have Children

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, associations

I have a 2 models in Rails 4

```
 course.rb
 has_many :reviews

 review.rb
 belongs_to :course
```

What is the best way to scope only the courses which have been reviewed? Here are two ways:

```
 1. scope :with_reviews, -> { joins(:reviews).where(:reviews => { :id => !nil }) }
```

counter_cache: true in review.rb and

```
 2. scope :with_reviews, -> { where('reviews_count > ?', 0) }
```

Is there another better way to do so?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Course.joins(:reviews).group('reviews.course_id').having('count(reviews.id) > 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :with_reviews, -> { joins(:reviews).select("DISTINCT courses.*")}
```